# Simple cloud backup solution for Windows Server 2016

Tags: backup, windows-server-2016, cloud, automation

I have an instance Windows Server 2016 hosted on a virtual machine by our provider. It hosts a bunch of ASP.NET applications.

My backup solution is very basic: A batch file is run once a week (scheduled with Windows Task Manager) which creates full backups of all databases. Then, once a week, I manually remote in to the server and zip all the backed up databases, (zip all the website folders as well), and upload to Google Drive (deleting the previous backup, which is its own PITA).

I'm looking for a utility or some software (ideally free, but I'm willing to pay) which will automate this process. Basically I want to be able to select which folders I need backed up, set a schedule, and leave the backup software to do its thing.

I'm sure Acronis would offer something but I fear this might be overkill. Any other solutions? Something that will provide cloud storage too ideally (I'd need around 5GB).

**edit:** I realize I'm asking for something for free that will also provide cloud storage. So, scratch that - I'm willing to pay. I just need some advice so I don't go for an unnecessarily loaded solution when I could get away with something simple.

**edit2 (sorry):** Realizing also that the downloadable Goog Drive has the functionality to sync a desktop folder. So maybe a freeware solution is possible? I'll clean up this whole post eventually...

Comment: Is this production data? Is it customer data? What would happen if you lost the data and had no backup?

Answer (score 0):

May be you would try using one of these : GoodSync , Duplicati , Gs Richcopy360 or FBackup  to backup to Google drive

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using Veeam Endpoint backup https://www.veeam.com/windows-endpoint-server-backup-free.html and then set the backup location to be on the OneDrive or Google drive ?

Comment: VEEAM free doesn’t support Server OS backup to OneDrive/Gdrive.
You can use free Duplicati or other tools from here: https://www.vmwareblog.org/single-cloud-enough-secure-backups-5-cool-cross-cloud-solutions-consider